# "Open Containing Folder" In Firefox & Chrome Doesn't Highlight The File In Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, downloads

I won't say I am new to Ubuntu, but I have been on and off for several years -- although I find myself on Ubuntu more than on Windows nowadays I still consider myself a newbie. I am currently using 13.10 and I also remember having this issue in 12.04 LS, as well.

After I download anything in Chrome or Firefox. There is this option in the downloads page of the browser (Ctrl+J) to open the file location. It is "Open containing folder" in Firefox and "Show in folder" in Google Chrome. When I click it these links in the downloads page of the browser, the "Downloads" folder opens as expected, but it still doesn't highlight the file in the directory. This becomes extremely painful to find the file especially if you have a ton of files in your Downloads folder. Of course I can switch to list view and sort the items by date and find the file. However, don't you guys think it should actually highlight the file when Nautilus opens?

It was already posted by some other user a month ago and I think the issue was not addressed properly. [Ubuntu Community Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205007&highlight=Open%20Folder%20Firefox)

Is it a bug or is this normal and something I have to deal with? I'm assuming it's a bug since the feature sounds pretty basic and its there on Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 3):

It's a longstanding issue which was reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9208) for Chromium. At that time, there was no way to select an individual item in a folder, only open the folder, and so was marked as fixed, with half of it being implemented. However, according to [this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632427) bug report, Nautilus has implemented the ability to select individual items, and it seems so has Dolphin (KDE equivalent of Nautilus). Perhaps it's time to open a new bug on this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you are on 13.10 or 12.04 can you check if this happens with your machine? Because I am having this issue with both 12.04 and 13.10 even after a clean installation.

Comment: Yes, it happens. It's "supposed" to happen because the selection part hasn't been implemented in Chromium or Firefox (well, at least Chromium, since that's what I use).

Comment: Thanks man. Then I guess we can do nothing much about it. Anyways, I am voting up your response even though I'm a bit disappointed. :(

Oops! Well I can't do that as well. "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

All the more misery. hehe

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=352988) at Chromium asking to take another look at this. If all goes well, this should appear in Chromium 35 or 36.

Comment: You are awesome, I keep my fingers crossed.

Comment: Chrome 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit) has implemented this feature